# shell script to 'make check' multiple times in Pintos

Tags: shell, pintos

Right now, I am working with Pintos, and
I want to do 'make check' multiple times at once by writing a shell script.

what I thought was making a test-five.sh file with

```
#!/bin/bash/

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    make -j 8 check
done
```

I thought running this test-five.sh file and then doing
test-five.sh > result.txt
would be alright.

However, I cannot figure out which directory I should place this file and
if this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner for loop to a count of 5:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo 'command output'; done
```

For your case:

```
for i in {1..5}; do make -j 8 check; done
```

Comment: at which directory should I place the shell script?
At the highest directory..?